# MySQLdb import error on windows 7 + Django

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

I installed `python 2.6`   and   `MySQL-python-1.2.2.win32-py2.6`   and created a new project using the command **django-admin.py startproject mysite**  and it successfully created the project and I could run it.But when I edit **mysite/settings.py**  file to use MySQLdb and run it again,it says

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by bound method Command.inner_run of dja
ngo.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x02BFCB
raise ImproperlyConfigured(Error loading MySQLdb module:)

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: DLL l
oad failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried searching all net and couldn't identify the problem.Is it to do with setting some environment variables? Can anyone please help me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fire up regular python and try

```
>>> import MySQLdb
```

and then fire up the django shell

```
> python manage.py shell
>>> import MySQLdb
```

and get the same error, I would presume that you have the wrong SQL package for your system - this is often a 32bit vs 64bit issue.

Dig out the actual SQL dll (called `_mysql.pyd` and see if you can import that directly into pyton (go to the directory containing the dll, fire up python and `import _mysql`). This should help speed up the diagnosis.

Alternatively, I've always found [Bitnami's django stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/django) to be the least painful way to install and manage my Windows django stack. It will set up and manage   Apache HTTP Server, MySQL, Python, SQLite, PostgreSQL, Django all in one go.

Comment: Wow!! The stack thing is really cool.It worked for me.Thanks a lot :)